# Unexpected behavior with reference and friend class

Tags: c++

I have an unexpected behavior using the friend keyword and a reference. Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

class Modifier;

class A{
 private:
     int _a;
     friend Modifier;
};
class B : public A {};

class Modifier
{
public:
    void f(A& i) { i._a = 10; std::cout << i._a << std::endl; }
};
int main()
{
    Modifier m;
    B b;
    m.f(b);
}
// Output
// 10
```

B shouldn't be able to modify the variable *_a*. Can someone explain me how it is possible ?

Comment: But you're not passing a `B` object to `Modifier::f`, but pass a reference to an `A` object. The function `Modifier::f` doesn't know anything about `B`.

Comment: *B shouldn't be able to modify the variable _a.* - why?

Comment: As a possible solution, create an overload of `f` that takes a reference to `B`, and mark it as deleted. I.e. `void f(B const&) = delete;`.

Comment: Access control only use the static type of the accessed object (the one that appear in the declaration of the reference parameter). I does not use the dynamic type of the object (the most derived type). If such a check had to be done, it could only be done at execution time.

Comment: you think `Modifier` cannot access `_a` because `B` inherits privately from `A`? If so, you should include that in the quesiton. It took me a while and I am still not sure why you think `_a` cannot be accessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> B shouldn't be able to modify the variable _a

`_a` and the object that contains it are non-const, so `_a` can be modified. Declaring a member private doesn't prevent a variable from being modified. Access specifier only affects the scopes where the name of the variable is accessible.

The class `B` *doesn't* modify the variable `_a`. It is `Modifier::f` that modifies `_a` variable (which is member of `A` base sub object of variable `b`). `Modifier` is a friend of class `A`, so members functions of  `Modifier` have access to privately declared names of `A`. Having access means that it can use the name `A::_a`.

Comment: I agree that it is Modifier::f that modifiies _a but we look at _a through i which is an instance of B. Does the compiler let the function bypass the private keyword ?

Comment: @BleakMidWinter `Modifier` is a friend, so it has access. The friend declaration "bypasses the private keyword" if that is how you would like to put it. Whether the `_a` is within a base of `B` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is already unable to modify `_a`, as it's declared private in `B`. It's only accessible in `A`. If you need to read `_a` from `B`, use protected getter:

```
class A {
    protected:
        auto get_a() const { return _a; }

    private:
        int _a;
        friend Modifier;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A **friend** class can access private and protected members of other class in which it is declared as friend. So, `_a` can be modified by any method of class `Modifer`. However, `B` can not modify `_a` because it is defined as private in class `A`. For example, if you would implement the method `f` in class `B`, then you would get compiler error which says `'int A::_a' is private`

```
class B : public A {    
    void f(A& i) { i._a = 10; std::cout << i._a << std::endl; }
};
```